# Submitted POST with Select from in variable throws exception

Tags: post, submit, internal, internal-server-error

I am submitting a POST form with a variable that accepts text input. I'm having an issue where, if the variable contains the two words "select" and "from" in the variable in that order but not subsequent, it gives an error 500 on the site. I do this on my development site and don't have the issue.

- Prod Server info:
- Linux version 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
  (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313)
- PHP Version 5.6.25
- Dev Server info:
- Linux version 3.13.0-93-generic (buildd@lgw01-13) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
- PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20

Sample POST output where error occurs:
[question] => 010101010101010101010101010101select0101010101010101010101010101from

I receive a 500 internal error and am unsure where to find the log files to get more info. Where do I start looking to resolve this?

I have searched google for "POST SUBMIT input select from causes 500 internal server error" and much more to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was the hosting firewall blocking certain keywords. We found that the keywords "delete " and " from " or "select " and " from " were being blocked from gaining access to the site. I'm adding some jQuery with regex to alert the user that specific keywords in certain orders cannot be used.

I'm open to any other suggestions for how to prevent this from occurring or what would be a better option.